# Adding a volt/amp-meter to a buck converter

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, noise

My buck converter is driving my volt/amp-meters crazy. As a hobby project I am trying to turn [this buck converter module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003161603344.html) into a variable power supply. I am trying to add a [voltage and current meter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32886740692.html) to it, but am not having success... I found where on the buck board there is a smaller buck converter to supply the electronics with 13V, I tapped into that, but there were large voltages between the separate supply and the output of the main unit. So I bought a [DC isolator](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001038056410.html) thinking that this should disentangle the two of them. Only kind of. Now the voltmeter keeps jumping around +- 1-2V from the true value measured with a [INNOVA 3320](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B000EVYGZA/). I suspect that the issue stems from the fact that 2 grounds are bonded inside the small voltmeter: one which is for supplying power to the voltmeter and the other where current is being measured between the load and the ground connection of the voltmeter. Putting the voltmeter on a 12V battery solves this issue and I hoped that the DC isolator would do the same, but it did not... Since I don't have an oscilloscope, I tried running the voltmeter off of the 12V dc isolator + a 5V linear regulator. Nope, not it.

Does anyone, perhaps, have some ideas of what is causing this odd behavior?

Comment: It appears that they request a separate supply for the meter. What happens when you just provide it with one? (By this, I mean ***not*** using some funky internal 13 V you discovered, but a genuine external DC supply like a stack of D cells or Lion or something. Should be easy to do as a test.) Does it work then?

Comment: that power supply has a voltage signal oputput for current and voltage, connect those to suitable volt-meters, (you may need to adjust the 0-5V signals to suit the voltage range your voltmeters expect. (or modify the dividers used in the voltmeters)

Comment: Yup, connected it to 3 series-bound 18650s and it's stable. But it's a bulky and clunky solution, ideally I'd like to power it from the same device.

Comment: Jasen Слава Україні, that's an interesting route I haven't considered...